# Le nom de l'objet qui sert à bloquer les vues d'un balcon ?

Tags: vocabulaire, anglais, terminologie

J'essaie de nommer un truc qui sert à bloquer les vues d'un balcon que l'on installe avec des attaches ou une corde que l'on passe dans les oeillets de la chose, ou on pourrait même faire serpenter le tout (souvent en polymère) entre les barreaux de la rampe du balcon, si il y en avait :

[image]

En anglais on trouve *balcony privacy screen* et des versions françaises de ces pages parlent de « brise-vue ».

De quoi s'agit-il ; *brise-vue* est-il le terme le plus courant et est-il compris et y en a-t-il d'autres ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On peut distinguer plusieurs types :

- **moucharabieh**, **claustra**

[image][image]

sont ajourées et permettent donc de voir à travers (de l'intérieur vers l'extérieur notamment). A ma connaissance, les moucharabieh couvrent généralement des fenêtres, de façon analogue aux [**persiennes**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/persienne).

[image]

- **paravent** désigne plutôt une séparation opaque intérieure au logement, classiquement qui tient debout avec un pliage "accordéon" :

[image]

- **panneau occultant** et **brise-vue** sont opaques et s'appliquent bien aux protections extérieures, la nuance étant que le panneau est rigide alors que le brise-vue peut être une toile flexible tendue, par exemple.

[image]

j'ajouterai le régional [**canisse**](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/canisse/12703) (provence), qui désigne un brise-vue fait avec des plantes type roseau (réel ou plastique), typiquement placées derrière un grillage.

[image]

S'agissant de la photo, le terme **brise-vue** me semble le plus approprié.

Answer (score 3):

Ca me fait penser aux littéraires *jalousie* et *[moucharabieh](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moucharabieh)*.

Plus couramment :

- *[paravent](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/paravent) extérieur*
- *Auvent latéral*
- *Store latéral*
- *[claustra](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/claustra)*
- *panneau [occultant](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/occultant)*

*Brise-vue* est aussi adéquat et compris, mais moins courant (je ne l'aurais pas utilisé spontanément). C'est *panneau occultant* qui me viendrait en premier à l'esprit.